# Meaning of slotSubscribe

Tags: rpc, slots, api, json, websocket

What does the slot in `slotSubscribe` *actually* mean? It is not `processed`, `confirmed`, or `finalized` from what I can tell.

Edit: The official documentation is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to receive notification anytime a slot is processed by the validator

`Parameters: None`

**Results:**
integer - subscription id (needed to unsubscribe)

**Request:**

```
{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "slotSubscribe" }
```

**Result:**

```
{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": 0, "id": 1 }
```

**Notification Format:**
The notification will be an object with the following fields:

```
parent: <u64> - The parent slot
root: <u64> - The current root slot
slot: <u64> - The newly set slot value
```

**Example:**

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "slotNotification",
  "params": {
    "result": {
      "parent": 75,
      "root": 44,
      "slot": 76
    },
    "subscription": 0
  }
}
```

[source](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#slotsubscribe)

Comment: I find the official description too vague. Why is there no commitment level param?

Comment: There is, it's in the first line. "Processed"